# Robohelp — TOC is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, robohelp

When I try to view the table of contents (TOC) online in Google Chrome which is generated using Robohelp, the TOC is not displayed in the left-side panel.

Please suggest me how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by downloading the most recent version of Adobe Robohelp 10.
I modified the appropriate files in accordance with the following site:
https://helpx.adobe.com/robohelp/kb/webhelp-issues-robohelp-versions-10.html

Followed the following instructions from Peter Grainge on https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2185300?start=40&tstart=0:

```
Open the following folder <install dir>\RoboHTML\WebHelp5Ext\template_stock
Create a backup copy for the following file whthost.js
Copy the original to a folder outside of Program Files.
Open the file whthost.js in a text editor with line numbering such as Notepad++.
In line 872 (RoboHelp 2015 and 2017) or line 868 (RoboHelp 10 and 11) change the following line from
sText = sText.replace("\n", "");
to
sText = sText.replace(/\n/g, "");
Save the edited file and copy it back to <install dir>\RoboHTML\WebHelp5Ext\template_stock overwriting the original
```

And regenerating the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start Chrome adding `--allow-file-access-from-files` to target.

Comment: Pavan likely wants to solve this problem for all site visitors.